# How to get contiguous physical memory of 10GB in Linux 2.6 kernel which has no CMA ?

Tags: linux, memory, driver, dma

I want to get contiguous physical memory on 10GB to test my DMA capable device (New Device). 
Can some one explain how to get contiguous physical memory to my driver? 
I also want to know how to map that memory to user space ? 
I am using on an 64 bit x86 Intel platform with 2.6.32 and 3.10 Linux Kernel versions. In that kernel version Contiguous Memory Allocation (CMA) is not present. I have 16GB RAM. 
From Google I got some clue, that kernel command line parameter mem=6G and ioremap can be used. 
But I am not clear how exactly to do it.

Please explain. 
How to get the physical address map of my 64 bit x86 Intel platform using Linux 2.6.32 Kernel? 
What kernel command line parameter should I use ? 
Can I do ioremap on RAM physical address ? If yes, what are the steps ? 
After mapping access to kernel space, how to map that memory to user space process?

I don't want to patch or recompile the Linux kernel.

Thanks in advance.